# Tasm Assembly Language Float

Tags: assembly, tasm

It's been 3 days since I started searching for an answer to my problem but I still don't have any luck solving it.

the Tasm file is a mini calculator, and it outputs int numbers, what I need is for it to output float numbers, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
msg1 db 13,10,13,10, "Enter 1st Number : $"
msg2 db 13,10, "Enter 2nd Number : $"
msgEr db 13,10, "Error $"
msgCh db 13,10, "Press A to ADD , S to SUBTRACT ,D to MULTIPLY, F to DIVIDE, X to EXIT : $ "
msgSum db 13,10,13,10, "Sum is : $"
msgDif db 13,10,13,10, "Difference is : $"
msgDiv db 13,10,13,10, "Quotient is : $"
msgMul db 13,10,13,10, "Product is : $"
tmp     db ?


.code

start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

lea dx, msg1
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
mov bx, 0

start1:
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
cmp al,0dh      
je next1
mov ah,0        
sub al,30h      
push ax         
mov ax,10d      
mul bx          
pop bx          
add bx,ax       
jmp start1      




next1:
push bx
lea dx,msg2
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov bx,0


start2:
mov ah,01h
int 21h
cmp al,0dh
je choice
mov ah,0
sub al,30h
push ax
mov ax,10d
mul bx
pop bx
add bx,ax 
jmp start2


choice:
lea dx, msgCh
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov ah, 01h
int 21h

cmp al,'f'
je dividing

cmp al,'a'  
je adding

cmp al,'s'
je subtracting

cmp al,'d'
je multiplying

cmp al,'x'
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

error:
lea dx,msgEr
mov ah,09h
int 21h 
jmp start


dividing: 
pop ax
div bx
push ax
lea dx,msgDiv
mov ah,09h 
int 21h 
pop ax
mov cx,0
mov dx,0
mov bx,10d
jmp break

adding:     
pop ax
add ax,bx   
push ax
lea dx,msgSum   
mov ah,09h
int 21h 
pop ax
mov cx,0
mov dx,0
mov bx,10d
jmp break   

multiplying: 
pop ax
mul bx      
push ax     
lea dx,msgMul   
mov ah,09h
int 21h 
pop ax
mov cx,0
mov dx,0
mov bx,10d
jmp break


subtracting: 
pop ax
sub ax,bx 
push ax
lea dx,msgDif
mov ah,09h
int 21h 
pop ax
mov cx,0
mov dx,0
mov bx,10d

break:
div bx
push dx
mov dx,0
inc cx
or ax,ax 
jne break 

ans:        
pop dx
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h
loop ans

jmp start

end start
```

Comment: It's clear that you need help, or you wouldn't be posting here. It's also useless to repeat the information you're providing in tags. If you remove all that useless content, it leaves *Language float*, which has no meaning. Instead of putting useless content in your title, use that space to more clearly describe the question you're asking or problem you're experiencing. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

### Print the whole division result decimal

I don't see any floating point operation in your code. Therefore I assume you are only interesting in printing out the result of a division, like 10/3 = 3.33333. The method is similar to the pen-and-paper-method: you repeatedly add a 0 to the remainder (= multiply by 10) and divide this new number.

`DIV` produces an integral part and a remainder. The integral part is to be converted as any integer described here and elsewhere. The remainder represents the fractional part. Mukltiply it with 10 and do one division. You get a decimal digit for the fractional part in `AX` and a new remainder which you can divide and so on. The work is done if the remainder is 0 or you have lost interest.

Example for 10,000 / 7:

```
MODEL small
.STACK

.DATA

    numstring db 30 dup ('$')
    first dw 10000
    second dw 7

.CODE
.386

; Convert integral part to decimal
ax2dec PROC STDCALL USES ax bx cx dx    ; Args: AX:number ES:DI: pointer to string
    mov bx, 10                          ; Base 10 -> divisor
    xor cx, cx                          ; CX=0 (number of digits)
  Loop_1:
    xor dx, dx                          ; No DX for division
    div bx                              ; AX = DX:AX / BX   Remainder DX
    push dx                             ; Push remainder for LIFO in Loop_2
    inc cx                              ; inc cl = 2 bytes, inc cx = 1 byte
    test ax, ax                         ; AX = 0?
    jnz Loop_1                          ; No: once more
  Loop_2:
    pop ax                              ; Get back pushed digits
    or al, 00110000b                    ; Conversion to ASCII
    stosb                               ; Store only AL to [ES:DI] (DI is a pointer to a string)
    loop Loop_2                         ; Until there are no digits left
    mov byte ptr es:[di], '$'           ; Termination character for 'int 21h fn 09h'
    ret
ax2dec ENDP                             ; Ret: ES:DI: pointer to terminating '$'

; Convert fractional part to decimal
dx2dec PROC STDCALL USES ax bx cx dx    ; Args: DX - Remainder from a division, ES:DI - pointer to string
    mov cx, 20                          ; maximal number of fractional digits
    @@LBL1:
    mov ax, dx                          ; Remainder
    xor dx, dx
    imul ax, 10
    div bx
    or al, 00110000b                    ; Conversion to ASCII
    stosb                               ; AL -> [ES:DI], DI++
    test dx, dx
    loopnz @@LBL1                       ; loop if ZF == 0 (test) and CX != 0
    mov byte ptr es:[di], '$'           ; Termination character for 'int 21h fn 09h'
    ret
dx2dec ENDP

main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax                          ; ES=DS for stosb

    xor dx, dx                          ; DON'T FORGET TO SET DX FOR DIV !
    mov ax, first
    mov bx, second
    div bx                              ; first/second -> AX remainder DX

    lea di, numstring
    call ax2dec                         ; Convert integral part to decimal
    test dx, dx                         ; DX (remainder) == 0?
    jz @@LBL2                           ; Yes -> no fractional procedure
    mov byte ptr [di], '.'              ; Set decimal point (ocerwrites '$')
    inc di                              ; ES:DI pointer to the next byte to be written
    call dx2dec                         ; Convert fractional part to decimal
    @@LBL2:

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, numstring
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Why do you OR with 48 (`00110000b`) when converting to ASCII as opposed to *adding* 48? (Or better yet, `'0'`.) I've never seen it done that way, and I can't figure out any way it is superior---just less obvious what's going on.

Comment: @CodyGray: I have sometimes to answer this question: "Why is the character '0' greater by 48 than the number 0?" This is my answer: It isn't greater, it is encoded in another way. An `OR` isn't more expensive then an `ADD` but you can see the idea and anticipate why 'A' isn't just behind '9'.

Comment: Sure, `ADD` and `OR` are equally efficient, that's not the issue. What you're saying is that you think `OR` is actually *clearer* than `ADD`, because you can explain it as changing the encoding? I guess that makes sense, but I think pointing to the ASCII table is even easier to understand. The character '0' is greater by 48 than the number 0 because the character '0' has ASCII code 48. And as I said before, the best (most obvious) way to write the code would be `ADD AL, '0'`. But it doesn't really matter, I suppose. I was just wondering if I was missing some trick. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: Yeah, it's not a trick, it's a matter of taste. :-)